# Terraform: Write a CloudFormation Template to disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

We are using Terraform along with a vendor supplied CloudFormation template.
It is all working except for when there are changes to the template. Terraform does not show you what will change as it's all contained within the template.
I was wondering if Terraform could write out the rendered CloudFormation template to disk where we could (in theory) use AWS native CloudFormation to create a change set to attempt to see the changes.
Any ideas if Terraform can write this out?

Comment: You could but only on an apply (plans should always be side effect free). Is that enough for you?

Comment: The main we are having is that the Terraform plan states that it will change the CloudFormation stack, but it cannot tell you what it will change.
On running the apply, most times it will not actually change anything.
It makes getting changes through the change board quite challenging.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform works by abstracting different infrastructure types into [providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/). In the case of AWS, the [AWS Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html) interprets your Terraform config into a set of AWS API calls. It does not internally create any CloudFormation templates, and has no understanding of or mapping to CloudFormation.

If you really want to use Terraform to describe changes made via CloudFormation you will likely have to create your own tool to convert CF templates into [Terraform Variable files](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html#from-a-file). As each new variable file is generated, you could run `terraform plan` to see what the outcome would be.